# references and pointers in the context of C++ classes

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I would like to ask a question about references and pointers in C++.

I am a beginner in C++ so I apologise for if the answer is trivial.

I have written the following code as part of a tutorial.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Deep {
private: 
    int *data;
public:
    void set_data_value(int d) {*data = d;}
    int get_data_value () {return *data;}
    // Constructor
    Deep (int d);
    // Copy constructor
    Deep (const Deep &source);
    // Destructor
    ~Deep();
};

Deep::Deep(int d) {
    data = new int;
    *data = d;
}

Deep::Deep (const Deep &source)
    : Deep (*source.data){ // main body of the constructor (delegation comes before the body)
        cout << "Copy Constructor - deep copy" << endl;
    }

Deep::~Deep() {
    delete data;
    cout << "Destructor deleting data" << endl;
}

void display_deep (Deep s) {
    cout << s.get_data_value() << endl;
}

int main () {
    Deep obj1 {100};
    display_deep (obj1);

    Deep obj2{obj1};

    obj2.set_data_value(1000);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code *works*. I will explain what I have done:

I defined a class named `Deep` to practice a deep copy. The pointer named `data` is private and I've included (and later defined) the function prototypes `set_data_value` and `get_data_value`.

`set_data_value` takes in an integer `d`, dereferences `data` and assigns the value `d` to it.
`get_data_value` simply returns the dereferenced value of `data`.

In the `public` domain also there is a constructor that accepts one integer `d`, a copy constructor which keeps the object constant and takes in a reference `&source` alongside a destructor.

Inside the copy constructor, I use a delegation constructor to improve the flow of the code.

However, if we observe the copy constructor

```
Deep::Deep (const Deep &source)
    : Deep (*source.data){ // main body of the constructor (delegation comes before the body)
        cout << "Copy Constructor - deep copy" << endl;
    }
```

we know that this is run upon the pass-by-value nature of `void display_deep (Deep s)`, so `source` is a reference to our `s` passed in. We then point to `source` and somehow obtain the value of data, which is then passed to the constructor.

How does this work? Does `*source.data` work as I described or does the compiler take a different route?

Comment: You already use `*data` in `get_data_value()`. That doesn't seem to raise questions for you. `*source.data` reads the value from `source` object in the same way. You could have written `source.get_data_value()` instead, to make it clearer.

Comment: `*source.data` is equivalent to `*(source.data)`. I.e. it takes the pointer `source.data` and dereferences it to the the value the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

> We then point to source and

There is no pointing to anything. In this line:

```
: Deep (*source.data)
```

You are just accessing the `data` inside `source`. Then you are *dereferencing* it. Just like you dereference `*data` to get the value inside it.